# How to use Ionic CLI with pnpm

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-cli, ionic-cli, pnpm

How is it possible to use pnpm or bun instead of npm with ionic cli?
it has some good benefits rather than npm, Like smaller storage usage, Showing progress when some package is downloading and etc...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run this command to change the default package manager of ionic CLI from npm to pnpm:

```
ionic config set -g npmClient pnpm
```

also if you want to use yarn or bun instead of npm :

```
ionic config set -g npmClient yarn
ionic config set -g npmClient bun
```

Comment: It helped me a lot, and a solution so simple! Thanks!